# Number of Russian Diplomats throughout USA

Tags: united-states, russian-federation, international-relations, embassy

The US expelled 60 Russian diplomats today, 26th March 2018. How many diplomats from Russia are in the US, at embassies, consulates, etc.?

Answer (score 3):

Officially, 455 Russian diplomats were active in the US before the March 2018 expulsion.

> *"Moscow retaliated by giving the US the deadline to reduce its diplomatic staff in Russia
>
>   to **455 people, matching the number of Russian diplomats left in the US** after Washington expelled 35 Russians in December."* — [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2017/jul/30/russia-us-sanctions-retaliation-sergei-ryabkov), 30 July 2017 (highlight mine).